# fs.statSync with Buffer "Error: Path must be a string without null bytes"

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, stat

I have read in a file buffer like this:

```
let imageBuffer
try {
  imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('/some/path/to/image.jpg')
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error reading in file', e)
}
```

Then I try to `stat` the buffer:

```
let imageStats = fs.statSync(imageBuffer)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Path must be a string without null bytes
```

But when I check the documentation it says that `statSync` accepts a `Buffer`:

> ```
> path: string | Buffer | URL
> ```

And I double checked that the Buffer is in fact a Buffer:

```
console.log(imageBuffer instanceof Buffer) // returns true
```

Also checked the size:

```
console.log(imageBuffer.byteLength) // returns 5928109 which is the correct size
```

So what am I misunderstanding here? Can you only `stat` a file path? The error makes it sound this way. But the documentation seems to make it clear that you can provide a Buffer too.

Bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The result of `fs.readFileSync('/some/path/to/image.jpg')` is not a filepath even if it is a buffer. Unless the contents of that file is a filepath. You should pass `'/some/path/to/image.jpg'` to `fs.statSync`

Comment: You may provide a filepath as either String, Buffer, or URL to `fs.statSync`. But a 6MB JPEG is not a filepath.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the documentation for [`fs.statSync(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path) is ambiguous.  I believe it is saying that it wants a **path**.  The path can be `<string> | <Buffer> | <URL>`, but it needs to be a path.

So don't give it the buffer of the whole file, you give it a buffer that, if turned back into a string, is the path to the file.

In other words,

- `fs.statSync("C:/foo.txt");`
- `fs.statSync(Buffer.from("C:/foo.txt"));`
- `fs.statSync(new URL("/foo", "https://www.example.com");`

If you think about it, it makes sense too.  How would an operating system be able to give you file system information about a a file's raw bytes?  Once it's bytes, it loses the context of the file system.  If you read in the contents of 2 identical files, their Buffers would be the same, yet the `stat` of either would give you different results.  You want to `stat` a path, not contents.

Comment: Ah okay that is making more sense now. Totally didn't consider that once a file is read into memory the filesystem wouldn't know any details about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does not say Buffer must be whole file content.

From [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) You can see that first argument is `path`.

You could be correct if You they wrote in manual that argument must be `body`, `content` or something alike.

So such code will work.

```
const imageFile = '/some/path/to/image.jpg';
let imageStats, imageBuffer;

try {
  imageStats = fs.statSync(imageFile);
  imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imageFile);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error reading in file', e)
}
```

But I'm sure we should require community to add examples in documentations.

Otherwise it's ambiguous.